# Fields being recognised as empty in javascript

Tags: javascript

The problem is that the text that is entered in the inputs aren't being recognised and are giving me a null value.

```
function checkInput(name, surname, email, comment) {
    if (name !==null &&  name!== '') {
        if (surname !==null &&  surname!== '') {
            if (email.value == '') {
                if (validateEmail(email)) {
                    if (comment !==null &&  comment!== '') {
                        window.alert('Valid inputs')
                    } else {
                        window.alert('You have not entered in a comment')
                    }
                } else {
                    window.alert('Email is not valid.')
                }
            } else {
                window.alert('You have not entered an email')
            }
        } else {
            window.alert('Please enter a surname')
        }
    } else {
        window.alert('Please enter a name')
    }
}
```

I also tried doing this but still nothing. Seems like the problem is coming from the if statements but I'm not really sure why it's isn't working as I want it to

```
function checkInput(name, surname, email, comment) {
    if (name.value == '') {
        if (surname.value == '') {
            if (email.value == '') {
                if (validateEmail(email)) {
                    if (comment.value == '') {
                        window.alert('Valid inputs')
                    } else {
                        window.alert('You have not entered in a comment')
                    }
                } else {
                    window.alert('Email is not valid.')
                }
            } else {
                window.alert('You have no entered an email')
            }
        } else {
            window.alert('You have not entered a surname')
        }
    } else {
        window.alert('You have not entered a name')
    }
}
```

Comment: Share how you are calling the function

Comment: `null !== undefined`

Comment: They are not working because you're checking for other inputs only if a previous one is empty - instead of checking for every one - separately. What if (theoretically) you had 30 inputs? You would nest that way 30 if statements?

Comment: `if (surname !==null &&  surname!== '') {` can be shortened.  Strings are only truthy if they're non-empty.  `if (surname)` will suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an answer that used js, but this answer is way simpler and works faster

```
<form>
<input required>
<br>
<input required>
<br>
<input required>
<br>
<input required>
<br>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

If you add the required atribute to an input or select, when the form is submitted but with no data in the input or select , it creates a banner stating that the input is required.

```
<select required>
    <option value="" selected disabled hidden></option>
    <option></option>
</select>
```